# Python, handle persistent http connection in web application

Tags: python, django, tweetstream

I'm in a bit over my head as a beginner with python, but I've managed to setup a connection to the twitter streaming api via a Django application and [tweetstream](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweetstream).

Within the application I can do the following and get a constant stream of tweets outputted to the console via the django test web server.

```
with tweetstream.FilterStream(arg, arg, arg, arg, arg) as stream:
   for tweet in stream:
       print tweet
```

I can also do something like this so I can query the stream for information.

```
my_tweetstream = tweetstream.FilterStream(arg, arg, arg, arg, arg)
print my_tweetstream.variable
```

Ideally, I'd like to start tweetstream so that it's able to log tweets, but also be able to visit an admin page which on refresh would query the connection and return data on how long it's been connected, how many tweets have been returned etc

The problem is I have no idea how this can be done with the code I have got so far.  For instance, how can i 'store' the connection so i can query it?

Please would someone mind explaining the right approach to going about this, and which resources might help me understand the problem better?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'd probably have the `tweetstream` grab tweets in a separate background (daemon) process, and put them into a database table or somesuch, along with any administrative information you want, like how long the process has been running for. Then your Django application can just read from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this recently for a project. You'll need to run the stream consumer as a separate python process. It doesn't need to be part of your Django application at all.

Basically I had:

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

from myproject.myapp.utils import do_something_with_tweet

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        do_something_with_tweet(data)
        return True

def main():
    listener = StdOutListener()

    auth = OAuthHandler(
        TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
        TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)

    auth.set_access_token(
        TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET)

    try:
        stream = Stream(auth, listener)
        stream.filter(track=['#something', ])
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print 'Stopping Twitter Streaming Client'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way you can run this as a separate process and pass the tweet data to some function to save it or whatever and Django can run happily elsewhere.

Plus points would be to use celery to process your tweet data in asynchronous tasks: https://celery.readthedocs.org

Comment: it could be easier to integrate with the OP's django app if this is run as a custom management command?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my main issue is not running the connection and using it to store information, I am stuck trying to  communicate with the running process from Django.

Comment: @dm03514 yeah a management command would make life a little easier, could also plug into the auto reload stuff so it restarts on code changes in dev.

Comment: @rix I'm not sure what your after, the Django thread won't be able to talk to your Streaming Thread, you'll have to store the data your getting from the streamer somewhere, like in a Django model or better yet Redis or other NoSQL solution.

Comment: @krak3n i see how this can work now, thanks.  But I still fail to understand how i can stop/start the script from django and that is the most important detail.  Have you any idea how to do that please?

Comment: @rix sure: python twitter_streamer.py

You could also write a django management command as dm03514 suggested or you can make an upstart script for it: http://pastebin.com/TJHixN4F

Comment: @krak3n - thanks, I'm ready to get started.  Really appreciate your help.  Thank you.